# How to form src value in runtime in scriplet tag and use it in expression tag?

Tags: java, jsp

I have been trying to set the image file path in runtime which varies with environment. So i have to form the path using a parameter from request object in runtime and append it to the "poweredby.gif" file name.

From my .jsp file :

```
<%
    String tempPath = "/poweredby.gif";
    String srcPath =request.getParameter("STRING_URL");
    String newPath = srcPath + tempPath;
%>
<img id=Image name=Image src="<%= newPath %>" border="0"></a>
```

This doesn't work , and newPath variable contains only the value of srcPath..so how do i append the "poweredby.gif" to the src so that it can pickup the image?

I have seen many articles where i couldn't find relevant information for my scenario

Comment: Include your attributes inside qotes, the right-click in your browser, click "View Page Source", and copy and paste the relevant part of the generated HTML in your question. Then learn NOT to use scriptlets, and to use the JSP EL instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry that was a typo , i gave the value in double quotes.. Any way i was able to solve the problem, actually the url that i was getting had lot of spaces , so i did a trim on the url and did append :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you forgot to put the double quotes `"` and then, when reached the `/` of `/poweredby.gif`, the HTML parsing is break.

Use this:

```
<img id="Image" name="Image" src="<%= newPath %>" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry that was a typo , i gave the value in double quotes.. Any way  i was able to solve the problem, actually the url that i was getting had lot of spaces , so i did a trim on the url and did append :)